# SOLR - Request the last result with sort parameter is slow

Tags: sorting, solr, pagination

I indexed 2M+ documents and when I request the last result order by name, the response is very slow (18s).
Is there a wy to optimize the sorting ?

My request :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/items/select?&q=*:*&start=2274000&rows=100&sort=name_sort asc&fl=id,name
```

Below is the field definition in `schema.xml` file

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<!-- docValues are enabled by default for long type so we don't need to index the version field  -->
<field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>

<field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="name_sort" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" />
```

Comment: Deep pagination (start=2274000) is known to be slow in Solr. In this case you might be better of sorting descending in your query and fetching from a page closer tot he top (start=0, start=100, ... )

Comment: As said by Hector, Solr is not designed for this usage. You might want to use cursor queries for better performances if absolutely need to go in deep pages. Or the `/export` handler if you are actually looking for retrieving all documents matching.

Comment: @HectorCorrea Gaël.
Thank you for your annswers. 
It allowed me to see more clearlier